# Evaluating the line integral $\int_c = 4x^2ds$ from $(-2,-1)$ to $(1,2)$

Tags: calculus, line-integrals

Here is what I've done.

We know that to solve this we must evaluate $\int_c = f(x(t),y(t)\sqrt{(\frac{dx}{dt})^2}+(\frac{dy}{dt})^2dt$

So we parametrize our x and y values.

$r_0 = (-2,-1)$ and $r_1 = (1,2)$

$r(t) = ((1-t) \times (-2,-1)) + (t(-1,2)$

$= x = -2+2t-t$ and $y = -1+t+2t$

So $\int_c = f(x(t),y(t)\sqrt{(\frac{dx}{dt})^2}+(\frac{dx}{dt})^2 = $$\int_{0}{1} = f(4(-2+2t-t)\sqrt{(12x^2)^2}dt$

$=[4(-2+2t-t) \times (\sqrt{12x^2})^2]_01$

$=4[(-2+2(1)-1) \times (\sqrt{12(1)^2})^2 ] - 4[(-2+2(0)-0) \times (\sqrt{12(0)^2})^2 ]$

1. I'm not sure over which interval is the integral evaluated? Would it just simply be between 0 and 1? As this is what I've done, but not sure whether thats right.
2. Is my parametrization right? I know the formula is $(1-t) \times$ the starting point $+t \times$ the end point. But I get numbers as well and I'm not sure whether I've classified them right for x and y.

Comment: Your working can get better. You write $x = -2+2t-t$ and then continue with that without simplifying to $x = t - 2$. Same for $y$. Also your question says the end point is $(1, 2)$ but you go on to solve as if the end point was $(-1, 2)$. Also your $dx/dt, dy/dt$ is wrong. Check it. In fact you do not need to do any of that. The way you are parametrizing, your ds = $|(1, 2) - (-2, -1)| = |(3, 3)| = 9 \sqrt2$.

Answer (score 0):

Segment from $(-2,-1)$ to $(1,2)$ has parametric equations

$C:(x=3 t-2,y=3 t-1), \;0\le t\le 1$

$ds=\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}=\sqrt{9+9}\,dt=3\sqrt 2\,dt$

$$\int_C 4x^2\,ds=\int_0^1 4(3t-2)^2 \cdot 3\sqrt 2\,dt=12 \sqrt{2}$$

Comment: How did you arrive at the parametrization?